# Abelian Subgroups of $Q_8$ and $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What are the abelian/commutative subgroups of the quaternion group of order 8 and the alternating group? How does one go about in determining this? Are there theorems that relate normal subgroups to being abelian?

Comment: What are the subgroups of $Q_{8}$ period? Have you drawn the subgroup lattice?

Comment: Yes the subgroups are generated by i,j,k,-1 and the identity according to the lattice.

Comment: Each of those are cyclic subgroups. What does that tell you?

Comment: Each of the subgroups are abelian! Therefore, m(Q_8)=1. Thank you! What about for A_4? After drawing the subgroup lattice, I see that <(12)(34),(13)(24)> generates subgroups and has 2 elements whereas the other generators are in sets of 1. Does that imply m(A_4)=2?

Comment: Think of the elements of $A_{4}$. The elements of $A_{4}$ are the distinct $3$-cycles in $S_{4}$, and pairs of disjoint transpositions. Can you find a copy of $V_{4}$ in $A_{4}$? Are there any nonabelian subgroups? If so, what are the generators? (A hint: there are $10$ subgroups of $A_{4}$. List the cyclic ones first, then find $V_{4}$. Show that any $3$-cycle and pair of disjoint transpositions generates the whole group.)

Comment: @KangHoonYou What does $\;m(Q_8)=1\;$ mean?